# No module named 'googleapiclient'

Tags: python

I've been thinking of remaking a video like Tom Scott's (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxV14h0kFs0)
as a small Youtuber and a newbie programmer and so I found a tutorial how (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4xtZv5nFIk) and I'm on the part where I run the code(5:00) and I'm pretty sure I have the same code as him but it says `import googleapiclient.discovery ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'`, where can I get the module googleapiclient? I'm not sure where I'm missing at.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "title.py", line 3, in <module>
    import googleapiclient.discovery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
```

Comment: What did you get when you searched for the interface in your browser?  "Download Google API client" brings plenty of hits; what is your blocking point?

Comment: I cloned this >https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client< git and reran the file and still the same error

Comment: I see ... you have *not* installed googleapiclient.  You need to learn how to find and install packages on which your work depends.  Again, look for it in your browser, and then use `pip install`.  If you have troubles, look up tutorials on "how to install Python packages".  This is a tutorial research item, not a Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the module? Something like `pip install googleapiclient` on the command line?

Comment: After you commented this i cloned the google api python client (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) on the same folder and tried to run it again but still didn't work

Comment: I am not mentioning anything about cloning. You have to install external libraries to your virtual environment using `pip install`. Google "how to install packages using pip" and see documentation here voor Google API installation: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client#installation